malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x159089200: probably modified after being freed
% npx parcel index.html
(node:3374) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server running at http://localhost:1234
⠦ Building index.js...
node(3374,0x17422f000) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x1458d4e00: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x0
node(3374,0x17422f000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
node(3374,0x1719d3000) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x15513e600: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x4962353962663631
node(3374,0x1719d3000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      npx parcel index.html

I am getting this error. What can be done?
OS- Sonoma 14.5
I have tried re-installing NodeJS, re-installing node_modules and deleting .parcel-cache file.
